# C/C++ - getrawmonotonic was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, unix, g++, time.h

I'm trying to use [`getrawmonotonic`](https://docs.huihoo.com/doxygen/linux/kernel/3.7/include_2linux_2time_8h.html#a2ec018df7a5c90cd9e44a33f0bd8320d) function in my C++ application (this question should be the same for C).

I tried both of the following includes to no avail:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
```

Any idea how to get this function included?

I'm using GCC. Is there a special compiler option needed?

I am compiling on Ubuntu 20.

Comment: Do not tag both C and C++ except when asking about differences or interactions between the languages, even if you expect the answer to be the same for the different languages.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a function inside the Linux kernel. Programs can't call it, just like they can't call functions inside other programs.

You might be looking for the [clock_gettime](https://linux.die.net/man/2/clock_gettime) function with the argument `CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW`.